# Problems with memory allocation

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    char *buffer=malloc(1);
    char *temporary=malloc(1);
    int length=0;
    signed int character;
    for(length=0;(character = getchar())!=EOF;length++)
    {
        buffer[length]=character;
        if((length==0) || ((length%1000)==0))
        {
            temporary=realloc(buffer,length+1001);
            if(temporary!=NULL)
            {
                buffer= temporary;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error: Out of memory!\n");
                free(temporary);
                free(buffer);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    buffer[length]='\0';
    length-=1;
    while(length>=0)
    {
        printf("%c",buffer[length]);
        length--;
    }
    printf("\n");   
    free(buffer);
    //////////////free(temporary); //( HERE)
    return 0;
}
```

My program should read a string or a input textfile, store it, and then print it out backwards which is working. I just don't understand why I can't `free` the temporary value at end.  It's failing with a `double free error`.

I would like to know why I cant put a `free(temporary)` where I wrote "here".

If you want to point out another problem in my code i'm happy to learn something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this code executes the line

```
buffer = temporary;
```

two things happen.  First, the memory that `buffer` was holding is "leaked"; you no longer have that address to pass to `free()`.  Second, `buffer` and `temporary` now both point to a single piece of memory allocated by `malloc()` or by `realloc()`.  Thus, when you call `free()` on either `buffer` or `temporary`, you have freed that chunk of memory; to call `free()` again would be a double free error.

I suggest something like this:

```
if (length >= buffer_size)
{
    const size_t new_size = buffer_size + 1000;
    char *temp = realloc(buffer, new_size);
    if (!temp)
    {
        free(buffer);
        /* handle the error in some way */
    }
    buffer = temp;
    buffer_size = new_size;
}
```

Also, it is best practice to actually check for errors.  `malloc()` and `realloc()` can fail.

Also, there isn't much point in allocating a single byte of memory for each buffer.  You might as well start out by allocating 1000 bytes or whatever.

Also, the way you check to see if the buffer needs `realloc()` seems needlessly tricky.  I would suggest keeping a variable that tracks how long the buffer is, and call `realloc()` when the buffer is not long enough, and then store into the buffer after the `realloc()`.

EDIT: I think you got a bit confused about `temporary`.  Look at the code I put and you will see that I put the `temp` variable inside the block of code of the `if` statement.  It's more obvious how long `temp` will hold a useful value (not very long).  Declaring `temporary` at the outer scope, and also calling `malloc()` to put a byte into it, is just confusing.

Comment: If `realloc` fails, your suggestion will leak.

Comment: @KerrekSB, you are right and I'll fix it.